# Can devkit be used to make scopes, components, or transformers?

Tags: mule, mule-component

I want to create other things in devkit besides connectors.  Is that possible?  The simplest example would be creating a No-Op to go in those can't-be-empty "otherwise" choice branches.  I also think a lock scope would be useful so that bit of the flow could only be executed once at a time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create components by creating a @Connector with just Configuration fields and no connection management. If you are using the DevKit plugin, you can select that you want No authentication and this will create a stateless connector that has an @Configuration connection strategy.

Also, you can create @Transformer inside your connector. This [github project](https://github.com/pablocabrera85/json-place-holder-connector) has a simple connector that defines several transformers on it.

You can put an empty logger on those otherwise branches, or create your No-Op if you want.

Regarding your lock scope I'm not 100% sure if we can do that, but I think that if you configure your @Processor with the intercepting flag, your @Processor will be able to execute the following chain and get the result.

Something like:

```
@Processor(intercepting = true)
public Object shouldContinue(boolean cont, SourceCallback afterChain) throws Exception {
    if (cont) {
        return afterChain.process();
    }
    return null;
}
```

In this example cont is just a configurable flag on your @Processor that you use decide if you want to execute the rest of the chain or not.

If you need the MuleEvent:

```
@Inject
@Processor(intercepting = true)
public MuleEvent shouldContinueFullEvent(boolean cont, MuleEvent muleEvent, SourceCallback afterChain) throws Exception {
    if (cont) {
        return afterChain.processEvent(muleEvent);
    }
    return null;
}
```